# getting gmail calendars by oauth credentials in c# dot net framework 2.0

Tags: google-oauth

I want to read google calendars through oauth credentials for my desktop application.
I am done with following things

1. registered with google api console
2. got client id ,client secret key

Now as I was looking for some examples,which tells me that 
this can be achieved with dot net framework 4.0 with google calendar api v3.

But for some reasons i need to stick to dot net framework 2.0.
So how i can achieve this?

I am done with reading calendars with username and password but now need to read through oauth.

And As I was able to read contacts by oauth I am sure there will be some way to do this for calendars.
     Code for conatcts :

```
   RequestSettings ObjectRequestSetting= new RequestSettings("appname",
                "consumerkey", "consumersecretkey", "user", "domain");
   ContactsRequest objContactReq = new ContactsRequest(ObjectRequestSetting);
            ContactsService objService = new ContactsService("appname");
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect to OAuth2 with out using googles client librarys is a little tricky but it can be done.  I normaly use this method becouse i dont like having to release third party dll's with my applications.

The first thing you need is to build the URL that will get you the AutenticationCode.

```
public static Uri GetAutenticationURI(Autentication MyAutentication)
{
List postData = new List();
postData.Add("client_id=<strong>{Client ID}</strong>");
postData.Add("redirect_uri=<strong>{Redirect URI}</strong>");
postData.Add("scope=<strong>{Scope}</strong>" );
postData.Add("response_type=code");
return new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" + "?" + string.Join("&", postData.ToArray()));
}
```

The URI it returns should look something like this https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&response_type=code

You need to have a webbrowser control on your form someplace.  Where ever you want to call it do something like this.   It will open the screen for the user to authorise your aplication.

```
wbAuthenticate.Url = Autentication.GetAutenticationURI(myAutentication);
```

When the  wbAuthenticate_DocumentCompleted returns you need to rip the Autentication code out of the body of HTML. Don't bother trying to rip it from the title this isn't always corect.

Once you have an AutenticationCode you need to exchange it for a refreshtoken and a accesstoken.  The access token is the one you use for all your calls to the API.  You use the refreshtoken to get a new access token back after it expires which is normaly in an hour.   The only thing you need to save for next time is the RefreshToken.

I have code for all that in a blog post but its pritty big and i'm not sure about spaming that amount of code here.   http://daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/

Comment: I will surely try thanks.. but can you please explain
"response_type=code" means.

I created a sample url but  google says to be invalid parametres 
"Required parameter is missing: response_type"

Comment: response_type=code is just telling the Oauth server that you want it to return you a AutenticationCode.   Its the 4th line in the postdata above. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#sendauthrequest

Comment: but as i am  using dotnetframework 2.0 I am not able to prefered google calendar api v3.

Comment: you dont have to use the API you can code all the requests yourself.   You will have to build each of the URL strings and write something to handle the web posts.  And decode the results comeing back to you.  wont be easy but its doable.

Comment: I tried your code, google still shows invalid request for token.

my uri is similar to this 
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&amp;
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly&amp;
response_type=code


I am new to this ,can u plz tell what went wrong.

Comment: I just checked the code some where along the like & got replaced with &amp;  I fixed the example and added a little line showing you what the url should look like for yours.

Comment: Go to the Oauth Playground and use it to mirror what your app is doing. The compare the http requests to see what you are doing differently.